# Spring Data Neo4j template.fetch() leading to OutOfMemory?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Is there a theoretical possibility that using `template.fetch()` could lead to OutOfMemoryException? Let's say for example that there is a loop that loops 100 times and each time `template.fetch()` is called. That would be something like this:

```
List<Building> buildings = repository.getBuildings();
for(Building b : buildings) {
    Country c = repository.include(b.getCountry()); // this calls template.fetch()
    // do something with country..
}
```

After a certain amount of loops the fetching gets really slow and then it throws OutOfMemoryException. Could the fetching be the problem and if this is the case how can this be handled?

Cheers

Comment: Fetch just loads objects in memory, either modify your code in order to not load every object in memory or increase your memory size, besides that I don't think there could be other solutions.

Comment: Thanks @remigio! Do you know if there is a way to remove the loaded in memory objects during runtime?

Comment: Objects fetched from neo4j are no different from plain Java objects, so they are removed by the garbage collector when going out of scope. In your case, being them assigned to local variables inside a for loop, they are marked to be garbage collected as soon as the for loop ends.

Comment: Thanks, man! If you want post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch just loads objects in memory, you should either modify your code in order to not load every object in memory or increase your memory size.
By the way, since objects fetched from neo4j are no different from plain Java objects, they are removed by the garbage collector when going out of scope. In your case, being them assigned to a local variable inside a for loop, their life extends from the assignment time to the next assignment and even the last assigned one dies as soon as the loop terminates.